# Saved macro to do substitution without hitting return and remaining in current position

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a macro that I save/configure in my .vimrc with `let`.  Without the `^M`, I have to hit return after typing `@b`.  With `^M`, it goes to the line of the last replacement.  I'd like to remain in the current position from which the macro was executed.

What is a way to use `let` to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

```
let @b=':%s/searchterm/blah/g^M'
```

Comment: are you trying to keep the cursor in the same position?

Comment: Yes, edited to be more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set up your macro to mark the current position so you can return there after the substitutions have finished:

```
let @b='mc:%s/searchterm/blah/g^M`c'
```

Comment: Change `' 'c` to `c so you get a perfect result !

Comment: Worked. Thanks.  Is using `^M` the only way to tell the substitution command to proceed?  I tried <cr> and <return> to no avail.